# Como calcular o frete por CEP no WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress

Gostaria de saber se é possível ter um valor de frete para cada CEP no Woocommerce ou só é possível um preço fixo.

Comment: Você chegou a olhar a documentação? Sua dúvida é sobre a interface ou sobre alguma parte do código? Está usando algum módulo?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhum módulo @brasofilo. Olhei a documentação e só é possível adicionar o frete fixo para um CEP de destino e não preços diferentes para diferentes localidades. Queria saber se era possível fazer isso.

Answer (score 4):

Depende da empresa que você quer usar para entregar.

Hoje tem pronto o meu plugin para os Correios: http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-correios/

Também existe da https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-jamef/

Além que em breve vou ter terminado um plugin para integrar com a Braspress.

Comment: Mas esse plugin é necessário escolher o tipo de entrega feita pelo correios. No meu site a entrega é feita por mim mesmo sem somar peso e altura do produto.

Comment: Então me explica como você "calcula" o valor dessa "entrega própria" sem peso e/ou dimensões do pacote que eu te explico como fazer no WooCommerce ;D

Mas parece então que você vai ter que criar um método de entrega próprio (um plugin para entrega) para calcular a entrega pelo CEP, mas tem que ter um processo e uma formula para calcular isso antes.